# Add formula into function

Tags: r

I have this example data

```
    install.packages('neuralnet')
    library(neuralnet)    
    DV<-runif(20,min=-3,max=3)
    RV_1<-runif(20,min=-3,max=3)
    RV_2<-runif(20,min=-3,max=3)
    formula<-'RV_1+RV_2'
    df<-data.frame(DV=DV,RV_1=DV_1,RV2=RV_2)
```

and I learn the neural network this way

```
neuralnet(DV~RV_1+RV_2,data=df,hidden=5)
```

and everything works well.

But if I need to use it in function for more combinations I need to use it like

```
testfun<-function(x,y){
  nnet<<-neuralnet(x~y,data=df,hidden=5)
}
testfun(DV,formula)
```

Which doesn't work
I've tried these approaches

```
testfun<-function(x,y){
  nnet<<-neuralnet(print(x,quote=FALSE)~print(y,quote=FALSE),data=df,hidden=5)
}
```

or

```
testfun<-function(x,y){
  nnet<<-neuralnet(as.symbol(x)~as.symbol(y),data=df,hidden=5)
}
```

or

```
testfun<-function(x,y){
  nnet<<-neuralnet(get(x)~get(y),data=df,hidden=5)
}
```

But nothing works. The problem is that I cannot change the `formula` object and I still cannot go trough.

Any advices how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you using `<<-` and not defining a proper return value for your function?

Comment: Rather than writing your own function, see `?update`.

Comment: What's wrong with the `as.formula` function? (And the comment about not needing to use "<<-" is correct.)

Comment: You seem to be mixing up formulas, names, and characters. All of those are distinct data types in R and you can't just smash them together. From your call it's unclear whether you want `x` to be passes in as a vector of values are you appear to be doing, or whether you want to pass in an unquoted name of a variable in the data.frame. Clearly you are passing in `y` as a string/character, but is there a reason for that?

Comment: Using <<- is my mistake. It is not necessary (my mistake during creating question example) and return of function also.

Comment: @MrFlick for x has to be  called values of the object which has same unquoted name. So vector in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
testfun<-function(x,y) {
    neuralnet(as.formula(paste(x, "~", y, sep ="")), data=df, hidden=5)
}

nnet <- testfun("var1", "var2")
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. And what about if A<-5
B<-10
vector<-"A,B" and I need call it like c(vector) and the results should be 5,10? I cannot use as.vector in right way it seems...

Comment: `eval(parse(text = paste("c(", vector, ")", sep ="")))` but the better way is to just `c(A, B)` instead of defining `vector <- "A,B"`

Comment: It helped me a lot in my project. Thank you for help